# Triple integral evaluation mass of object

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Can someone please check this for me as I'm not familiar with the topic yet.

Calculate the centre of mass of the region in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ specified by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2, z \geq 0$
and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, assuming the density is constant.

I found the mass and $z$-th moment using spherical coordinates.

$$\text{Mass} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{1} r^2\sin{\phi}\, dr\,d\phi\, d\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}\left(2 - \sqrt{2}\right)$$

$$\text{M}_z = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{1} r^3\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi}\, dr\,d\phi\, d\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

Not sure if I am setting this right since I'm  not getting the final answer.

The final given answer is $\left(0,0,\frac{3}{8}(2 - \sqrt2)\right)$.

Thank you.

Comment: You just about have it! Since you're symmetric about the $z$ axis, the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are 0. For the $z$ coordinate, it's equal to $\frac{M_z}{Mass}$

Comment: So is the answer wrong? since i computed the massand M_z correctly?

Comment: shoudn't the mass just be $2\pi/3$